# How can I suggest a feature for Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I would like to suggest a feature for Firefox.

What steps do I have to follow to suggest a feature?

Comment: I'm a bit unconvinced about the topicality of this question. It's not really about computer hardware or software but is instead about how to contact a company that happens to make software. You could ask the same about any company. In any case the first step should always be to speak to the manufacturer, either via their site or their publicly available details.

Comment: I do understand your argument and it does make sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to suggest improvements. The simplest is to use

Help > Submit Feedback

A more complicated way is to file a "bug" in the bug tracking system, as a request for enhancement.

A third way is to subscribe to one of Mozilla's many discussion lists, whichever seems most relevant. Many have their archives online, such as the "usability" list: https://lists.mozilla.org/listinfo/dev-usability

However, in the short run, there actually is a hidden setting to increase the number of closed windows and tabs Firefox lets you access.

In a new tab, type or paste about:config in the address bar and press Enter. Click the button promising to be careful.

In the filter box, type or paste session and pause while the list is filtered

Double-click browser.sessionstore.max_windows_undo and set the number of windows you can re-open. (I chose 10, because I tend to use news windows quite a bit.)

Double-click browser.sessionstore.max_tabs_undo and set the number of tabs you can re-open in the current window.

Bear in mind that session information is saved to disk every 15 seconds (by default), so remembering more may slightly increase the background workload.

Link that I took from
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/966900#answer-463607

Comment: The question has nothing to do with stored sessions. Where is that coming from?